# how does spark to get the sum count and max date together

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

For example I have the following records with the columns as:
(Country,City,Date,Income)

```
USA SF 2015-01 80
USA SF 2015-03 60
USA NY 2015-02 30
```

I need to group by the Country&City, and then to get the max date and the sum of income.
I tried to use two aggregations and one join to finish the requirement, such as:

```
val groupDateRdd = rawRdd.map(tp=>((tp._1,tp._2),tp._3)).reduceByKey(max())
val groupSumRdd = rawRdd.map(tp=>((tp._1,tp._2),tp._4)).reduceByKey(sum())
val resRdd = groupDateRdd.join(groupSumRdd)
```

Is this ok please, or any other better solution please, I have one concern how should I get the max date, does Spark provides suitable date or time format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a join. You can do this with a simple reduceByKey:

```
val result = rawRdd.map(tp => ((tp._1,tp._2),(tp._3, tp._4)))
                   .reduceByKey((v1, v2) => (maxDate(v1._1, v2._1), v1._2 + v2._2))
```

The output will look like this:

```
((USA,NY),(2015-02,30))
((USA,SF),(2015-03,140))
```

Comment: That's awesome Glennie :)

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the final join and use `combineByKey()` to do something along the lines of:

```
val resRDD = rawRDD.map { case (country, city, date, inc) =>
  ((country, city), (date, inc))
}.combineByKey(
  (date: String, inc: Double) => (date, inc),
  (acc: (String, Double), (date: String, inc: Double)) => (maxDate(date, acc._1), inc + acc._2),
  (acc1: (String, Double), acc2: (String, Double)) => (maxDate(acc._1, acc._2), acc._1 + acc._2)
)
```

You would obviously have to implement your own version of `maxDate()` per your date format but this should produce a `(maxDate, summedIncome)` value tuple for each country-city pair.

Comment: Thank you Rohan, I know your answer is in a right way, but I could not compile it when I copied your code to my IDE. It's seems some syntax error. I spent a lot time but I could not fix it. Could you please fix it. I only copied over the code in combineByKey(...)

Comment: btw, I wrote the maxDate function: def maxDate(date1:Date,date2:Date):Date={
      if(date1.after(date2))return date1
      return date2
    }

Comment: Hey @Jack, after looking at the solution Glennie provided, I would use that instead since combineByKey is designed for when your return type from the aggregation is different from the values being aggregated (reduceByKey provides a more elegant solution here).